# Sequence containers - why all containers do not all methods

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I was learning C++ Sequence containers by referring below information - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container `[Member function table - functions present in C++03 ,- functions present since C++11, - functions present since C++17, - functions present since C++20]`
available at the end of the page.

What I am unable to understand reasons why all sequence containers support at least if not all basic methods like:

```
forward_list does not supports size()
vectors does not support emplace_front()
arrays does not support capacity()
deque does not supports reserve()
list does not supports emplace_hint()
```

Similarly there are other features which are available in all?  Basically what features or functionality decides which method is available for one container and not for other?

Comment: What would `emplace_hint` do on a list?

Comment: The question is unclear to me, because you seem to imply that the "not supports" are possible. And I think they are not, some of them "obviously". So please add info on why/how you think they would be possible to implement for the container in question. Or are you asking for reasons why they are not implementable? Then you should clarify that in the question.

Comment: "Container" in this context is just a word describing structures that contain something. There is no "container" interface. Every structure has its own methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> forward_list does not supports size()

std::forward_list is designed for maximum space efficiency, so the size is not kept as an extra member (it is in std::list). To determine the size one would have to walk the list, O(N).

> vectors does not support emplace_front()

To insert at the front, the std::vector would first need to shift the existing content. Again, O(N). This is where std::dequeue comes into play.

> arrays does not support capacity()

std::array has a fixed size, capacity() would not make sense, at best it would be a replicate of size().

> deque does not supports reserve()

It does not make sense to reserve for a std::deque as it does not use continous storage.

> list does not supports emplace_hint()

There is no use case for emplace_hint() on a std::list, you can simply use emplace().

Comment: "*std::forward_list is designed for maximum space efficiency, so the size is not kept as an extra member (it is in std::list).*" The size isn't missing for space efficiency; it's for *insertion* efficiency. Without a size, `splice` functions for iterator ranges can just be a couple of pointers. If there was a size, the function would have to walk that range to figure out how many elements were added. Without a size, an O(n) insert becomes an O(1) insert.

Comment: @NicolBolas Do you have a source for that? std::list offers both `size()` and `splice()` and therefore has the O(n) complexity in `splice()`; since C++11 `size()` is required to be O(1). The documentation I found for `std::forward_list::splice_after()` also states O(n) which I found curious.

Comment: ... That is strange. O(n) splice_after makes no sense, especially when splicing an entire list. Splicing a range requires getting the iterator before `first`, but that's a different `n` from the number of elements being spliced.